# Amazon Elastic Load Balancing query api SetLoadBalancerListenerSSLCertificate

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use SetLoadBalancerListenerSSLCertificate http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_SetLoadBalancerListenerSSLCertificate.html from the Elastic Load Balancing api in my script

a sample ws call looks like (our elb is in us-east)

```
    https://elasticloadbalancing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=<Access Key Removed>&Action=SetLoadBalancerListenerSSLCertificate&LoadBalancerName=testelb&LoadBalancerPort=443&SSLCertificateId=arn%3Aaws%3Aiam%3A%3A984502586525%3Aserver-certificate%2FtestCert&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2012-03-08T15%3A49%3A00.181Z&Version=2011-11-15%29&Signature=TUJCVlu7ojVFo%2Bw234239cIyVEFQu7ShkiY345cCX5k%3D
```

this request is failing - i get an xml response back like

```
    <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/2005-15-09">
    <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidAction</Code>
    <Message>
    Could not find operation SetLoadBalancerListenerSSLCertificate for version 2011-11-15)
    </Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>3fb78e4b-6936-11e1-b35f-61bb55c2dcc3</RequestId>
    </ErrorResponse>
```

is there something wrong with the way I'm structuring my query that is causing this error? I'm sure the version is right as per the link I posted above gives that exact version number.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending

```
Version=2011-11-15%29
```

Which is `2011-11-15)`. Remove the %29 (right parenthesis) and it should work better.